# AJAX behaving differently for Submit button vs. this.form.submit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to auto-save a selection in a dropdown (ASP.NET, MVC, VB), but it's not behaving as expected. Here's the dummy action in the controller:

```
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)> _
Function TestAction(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
    Return Content(id)
End Function
```

and the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js") %>'></script>

<% Using Ajax.BeginForm("TestAction", New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "test"})%>
<%=Html.Hidden("id", 123)%>
<%=Html.DropDownList("actions", Nothing, New With {.onchange = "this.form.submit();"})%>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<span id="test"></span>
<% End Using%>
```

The Submit button works as expected - the span is populated with "123". The dropdown on the other hand opens a new page with nothing but "123" on it. Why "this.form.submit()" not doing the same thing as the Submit button? Is there a different call I should make to emulate the Submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.form.submit does not run the form.onsubmit event. Pressing the submit button, on the other hand, does. That, combined with [the HTML that Ajax.BeginForm generates](http://www.aspnetpro.com/articles/2009/06/asp200906de_f/asp200906de_f.asp), explains why the two behave differently. As for how to make your event do the same thing as pressing the submit button, look at the HTML in the linked article:

```
Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(
         this,
         new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event),
         { 
             insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace,
             updateTargetId: 'test' 
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but there is a new (and better) way to do this.

Instead of doing using javascript, use jQuery. Just had this issue and it worked great.

`this.form.submit()` <---- Javascript

`$("form").submit()` <---- jQuery